# firebase function deploy billing issue on blaze plan

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am getting below error. I have enable blaze plan but still getting billing account not
available after i run  `firebase deploy` command

```
  ⚠  functions[userLogin(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
    Function deployment failed because the billing account is not available.
    ⚠  functions[onUserStatusChange(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
    Function deployment failed because the billing account is not available.
    ⚠  functions[myFunction(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
    Function deployment failed because the billing account is not available.
    

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        myFunction
        onUserStatusChange
        userLogin
```

Comment: Can you check in the Google **Cloud** console if there is indeed a billing account associated with your project? If that seems to be the case, I'd [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting, as they can look at your project specifics.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed payment amount to $1 as it was unable to deduct less than $1 and i also changed the card in google Cloud Console and now it is working.

Comment: Good to hear Bilal! 

Comment: Thanks, @BilalRabbi but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for tracking, this was resolved by @bilal-rabbi changing the payment amount to $1 and also changing the Credit/Debit Card in the GCP Console.

Here's the original comment:

> Thanks for the help. I changed payment amount to $1 as it was unable to deduct less than $1 and i also changed the card in google Cloud Console and now it is working.